# bind fatal error cant open custom log

Tags: 14.04, permissions, dns, bind

I have been having problems with bind9 on 14.04 LTS

`sudo service bind9 start` produces next log

```
May 20 21:47:46 c1 named[1110]: starting BIND 9.9.5-3-Ubuntu -u bind
May 20 21:47:46 c1 named[1110]: built with '--prefix=/usr' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--sysconfdir=/etc/bind' '--localstatedir=/var' '--enable-threads' '--enable-largefile' '--with-libtool' '--enable-shared' '--enable-static' '--with-openssl=/usr' '--with-gssapi=/usr' '--with-gnu-ld' '--with-geoip=/usr' '--with-atf=no' '--enable-ipv6' '--enable-rrl' '--enable-filter-aaaa' 'CFLAGS=-fno-strict-aliasing -DDIG_SIGCHASE -O2'
May 20 21:47:46 c1 named[1110]: ----------------------------------------------------
May 20 21:47:46 c1 named[1110]: BIND 9 is maintained by Internet Systems Consortium,
May 20 21:47:46 c1 named[1110]: Inc. (ISC), a non-profit 501(c)(3) public-benefit 
May 20 21:47:46 c1 named[1110]: corporation.  Support and training for BIND 9 are 
May 20 21:47:46 c1 named[1110]: available at https://www.isc.org/support
May 20 21:47:46 c1 named[1110]: ----------------------------------------------------
May 20 21:47:46 c1 named[1110]: adjusted limit on open files from 4096 to 1048576
May 20 21:47:46 c1 named[1110]: found 2 CPUs, using 2 worker threads
May 20 21:47:46 c1 named[1110]: using 2 UDP listeners per interface
May 20 21:47:46 c1 named[1110]: using up to 4096 sockets
May 20 21:47:46 c1 named[1110]: loading configuration from '/etc/bind/named.conf'
May 20 21:47:46 c1 named[1110]: reading built-in trusted keys from file '/etc/bind/bind.keys'
May 20 21:47:46 c1 named[1110]: using default UDP/IPv4 port range: [1024, 65535]
May 20 21:47:46 c1 named[1110]: using default UDP/IPv6 port range: [1024, 65535]
May 20 21:47:46 c1 named[1110]: listening on IPv4 interface lo, 127.0.0.1#53
May 20 21:47:46 c1 named[1110]: generating session key for dynamic DNS
May 20 21:47:46 c1 named[1110]: sizing zone task pool based on 25 zones
May 20 21:47:46 c1 named[1110]: using built-in DLV key for view _default
May 20 21:47:46 c1 named[1110]: using built-in root key for view _default
May 20 21:47:46 c1 named[1110]: set up managed keys zone for view _default, file 'managed-keys.bind'
May 20 21:47:46 c1 named[1110]: command channel listening on 127.0.0.1#953
May 20 21:47:46 c1 named[1110]: isc_file_isplainfile '/var/log/named/query.log' failed: permission denied
May 20 21:47:46 c1 named[1110]: configuring logging: permission denied
May 20 21:47:46 c1 named[1110]: loading configuration: permission denied
May 20 21:47:46 c1 named[1110]: exiting (due to fatal error)
```

named.conf.log prevew

```
root@c1:/etc/bind# cat named.conf.log
logging {
    channel query_log {
        file "/var/log/named/query.log" versions 3 size 5m;
        // Set the severity to dynamic to see all the debug messages.
            print-category yes;
        print-severity yes;
        print-time yes;
        severity dynamic;
        };
    channel update_debug {
        file "/var/log/named/update_debug.log" versions 3 size 5m;
        severity debug ;
        print-category yes;
        print-severity yes;
        print-time yes;
        };
    channel security_info {
        file "/var/log/named/security_info.log" versions 3 size 5m;
        severity info;
        print-category yes;
        print-severity yes;
        print-time yes;
        };
    channel bind_log {
        file "/var/log/named/bind.log" versions 3 size 5m;
        severity info;
        print-category yes;
        print-severity yes;
        print-time yes;
        };
    category queries {
        query_log; 
        };
    category security {
        security_info;
        };  
    category update-security {
        update_debug;
        };
    category update {
        update_debug;
        };
    category lame-servers {
        null;
        };
    category default {
        bind_log;
        };
};
```

command `named-checkconf` returns no errors

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fix for the problem is in file permitions and apparmor

**Apparmor fix**

full file copy-paste exclude first line

```
root@c1:/etc/bind# cat /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.named
# vim:syntax=apparmor
# Last Modified: Fri Jun  1 16:43:22 2007
#include <tunables/global>

/usr/sbin/named flags=(complain) {
  #include <abstractions/base>
  #include <abstractions/nameservice>

  capability net_bind_service,
  capability setgid,
  capability setuid,
  capability sys_chroot,
  capability sys_resource,

  # /etc/bind should be read-only for bind
  # /var/lib/bind is for dynamically updated zone (and journal) files.
  # /var/cache/bind is for slave/stub data, since we're not the origin of it.
  # See /usr/share/doc/bind9/README.Debian.gz
  /etc/bind/** r,
  /var/lib/bind/** rw,
  /var/lib/bind/ rw,
  /var/cache/bind/** lrw,
  /var/cache/bind/ rw,


  # gssapi
  /etc/krb5.keytab kr,
  /etc/bind/krb5.keytab kr,

  # ssl
  /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf r,

  # GeoIP data files for GeoIP ACLs
  /usr/share/GeoIP/** r,

  # dnscvsutil package
  /var/lib/dnscvsutil/compiled/** rw,

  /proc/net/if_inet6 r,
  /proc/*/net/if_inet6 r,
  /usr/sbin/named mr,
  /{,var/}run/named/named.pid w,
  /{,var/}run/named/session.key w,
  # support for resolvconf
  /{,var/}run/named/named.options r,

  # some people like to put logs in /var/log/named/ instead of having
  # syslog do the heavy lifting.
  /var/log/named/** rw,
  #added line here
  /var/log/named/* rw, 
  /var/log/named/ rw,



  # Site-specific additions and overrides. See local/README for details.
  #include <local/usr.sbin.named>
}
```

**Bind9 fix**

next i have been changeing pemitions until it worked

/var/log/named changes

```
chown -R bind:root /var/log/named
chmod -R 775 /var/log/named
```

result of above commands

```
root@c1:/etc/bind# ls -lha /var/log/named/
total 196K
drwxrwxr-x  2 bind root   4,0K мај 20 20:38 .
drwxrwxr-x 18 root syslog 4,0K мај 21 00:46 ..
-rwxrwxr-x  1 bind root   6,8K мај 21 01:20 bind.log
-rwxrwxr-x  1 bind root      0 мај 20 19:30 bind.log~
-rwxrwxr-x  1 bind root   167K мај 21 01:21 query.log
-rwxrwxr-x  1 bind root      1 мај 20 23:14 security_info.log
-rwxrwxr-x  1 bind root      0 мај 20 19:30 security_info.log~
-rwxrwxr-x  1 bind root      1 мај 20 23:13 update_debug.log
-rwxrwxr-x  1 bind root      0 мај 20 19:23 update_debug.log~
```

/etc/bind changes

```
chown -R bind:root /etc/bind
chmod -R 774 /etc/bind
```

result of above commands

```
root@c1:/etc/bind# ls -lha /etc/bind
total 120K
drwxrwsr--   3 bind root 4,0K мај 21 00:33 .
drwxr-xr-x 150 root root  12K мај 21 00:34 ..
-rwxrwxr--   1 bind root 2,4K мар 24 18:06 bind.keys
-rwxrwxr--   1 bind root  237 мар 24 18:06 db.0
-rwxrwxr--   1 bind root  271 мар 24 18:06 db.127
-rwxrwxr--   1 bind root  237 мар 24 18:06 db.255
-rwxrwxr--   1 bind root  353 мар 24 18:06 db.empty
-rwxrwxr--   1 bind root  270 мар 24 18:06 db.local
-rwxrwxr--   1 bind root 3,0K мар 24 18:06 db.root
-rwxrwxr--   1 bind root  860 мај 20 18:54 named.conf
-rwxrwxr--   1 bind root 1,1K мај 20 18:49 named.conf~
-rwxrwxr--   1 bind root  490 мар 24 18:06 named.conf.default-zones
-rwxrwxr--   1 bind root  475 мај 20 22:24 named.conf.local
-rwxrwxr--   1 bind root  477 мај 20 22:22 named.conf.local~
-rwxrwxr--   1 bind root 1002 мај 20 23:12 named.conf.log
-rwxrwxr--   1 bind root 1002 мај 20 23:11 named.conf.log~
-rwxrwxr--   1 bind root 1,1K мај 21 00:33 named.conf.log.save
-rwxrwxr--   1 bind root 1,4K мај 20 18:50 named.conf.options
-rwxrwxr--   1 bind root 1,4K мај 18 23:23 named.conf.options~
-rwxrwxr--   1 bind root   77 мај 20 04:25 rndc.key
drwxrwxr--   2 bind root 4,0K мај 18 23:23 zones
-rwxrwxr--   1 bind root 1,3K мар 24 18:06 zones.rfc1918
```

**Notice:**

> This bind9 installation is not chrooted

now Bind9 is working

```
 root@c1:/etc/bind# service bind9 start
     * Starting domain name service... bind9             [ OK ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I came here because of a general bind startup permission issue.

It seems that bind will log that it is denied permission to named.conf whether or not that is actually the file which is causing the problem.

Apparently, the user that bind runs as has to have read write AND execute access to the zone files, but only needs read access to the other config files.

Answer (score 0):

I have apparmor installed but am not using it.

Creating the folder `/var/log/named` with permissions `bind:bind 755` was all I needed to do.  The log files themselves get generated with `bind:bind 644` permissions.